# Where does the value live after it's borrowed in the function?

Tags: rust

Consider below code:

```rust
fn main(){
    let mut s = "Hi".to_string();
    
    s.push_str(&" foo".to_string());
    
    println!("{}",s);
}
```

We send reference of `foo` (i.e, a **String** not str) in `push_str`. But, we are not storing `foo` in any variable and just sending the reference.

Where does the value `foo` live for the reference to be valid inside of `push_str`.

As I'm just borrowing `foo`, how can I refer to `foo` (as a reference) later in my code i.e, after `println`?

Answer (score 2):

Rust temporaries exist until the end of the current expression, and they can even be extended if necessary. The Rust compiler effectively creates a temporary variable for that temporary that you never see. This

```
s.push_str(&" foo".to_string());
```

is semantically equivalent to

```
{
  let tmp = " foo".to_string();
  s.push_str(&tmp);
}
```

Comment: How long does tmp live ? and how can I access tmp in the context of temporary

Comment: (1) Until the end of the current expression, or until its lifetime expires (lifetime extension can occur if the reference is help until the end of the current function, for instance). (2) You can't. If you want to, give it a name.

Comment: Until the end of the current statement, not expression.